# Filtrar datos con BindingSource

Tags: c#, windows-forms

que tal, me podrían ayudar, no se como hacer un filtrado de datos con BindingSource.
El BindingSource lo lleno de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
registroPercepciones2BindingSource.DataSource = new Registro_Percepciones_2() { Val = TP}.GetAll();
```

De esta manera lleno de datos el datagridview, pero quisiera poder filtrar los datos que estan cargados, sin llamar nuevamente a la base de datos, he intentado con esta linea:

```
source1.Filter = "artist = 'Dave Matthews' OR cd = "+ txtBuscar.Text +"";
```

Pero no me funciona.

Comment: Algo que podría funcionarte es guardar en memoria el source:
`var miFuente=new Registro_Percepciones_2() { Val = TP}.GetAll(); `
 y despúes en un método filtras esa fuente y la vuelves a asignar...
`registroPercepciones2BindingSource.DataSource= miFuente.Where(x=>x.artist=='Dave Matthews').ToList();`

Comment: Pero entonces, de todos modos estaría consultando directamente en la base de datos, y eso es lo que quiero evitar

Comment: No precisamente, cuando guardaste el `var miFuente` se guarda en memoria, la próxima vez que vuelvas a consultar esa variable ya no se realizará la llamada a la BD